# Difference between two files after average using shell script or awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have two files. Each has one column with some missing data as 9999, 9000. e.g.

```
ifile1.txt    ifile2.txt
30            20
9999          10
10            40
40            30
10            31
29            9000
9000          9999
9999          9999
31            1250
550           29
```

I would like to calculate the difference between the averages of the above two files without considering the missing values. i.e.

```
average (ifile1.txt) - average (ifile2.txt)
```

I tried like this, but not getting the result.

```
ave1=$(awk '!/\9999/ && !/\9000/{sum += $1; count++} END {print count ? (sum/count) : count;sum=count=0}' ifile1.txt)
ave2=$(awk '!/\9999/ && !/\9000/{sum += $1; count++} END {print count ? (sum/count) : count;sum=count=0}' ifile2.txt)

result=$(ave1-ave2)
echo $result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '!/9000|9999/{a[FILENAME]+=$0;b[FILENAME]++}END{for(i in a)c=c?c-a[i]/b[i]:a[i]/b[i];print c}' file1 file2
```

Update:

```
awk '!/9000|9999/{a[ARGIND]+=$0;b[ARGIND]++}END{print a[1]/b[1]-a[2]/b[2]}' file1 file2
```

or

```
awk '!/9000|9999/{a[ARGIND]+=$0;b[ARGIND]++}END{for(i=1;i<=ARGIND;i++)c=c?c-a[i]/b[i]:a[i]/b[i];print c}' file1 file2
```

Comment: My result is a negative value. But the above script is not giving negative sign. Can you please suggest how to do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Updated.  Maybe array order problem

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Can you please suggest me how can modify the script if I use a threshold. I have asked it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666553/difference-between-two-files-after-average-of-selected-entries-using-shell-scrip

Answer (score 1):

Your `awk` will compute the averages but bash won't do floating point arithmetic.  You can always use `bc` though.

```
$ echo "$ave1 - $ave2" | bc
```

-101.429

Also for expressions you have to use `$(( ... ))`