# Difference between two files after average of selected entries using shell script or awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have two files. Each has one column with some missing data as 9999, 9000. e.g.

```
ifile1.txt    ifile2.txt
30            20
9999          10
10            40
40            30
10            31
29            9000
9000          9999
9999          9999
31            1250
550           29
```

I would like to calculate the difference between the averages of the values (which are > 10) in the above two files without considering the missing values. i.e.

```
average ( the entries > 10 in ifile1.txt) - average (the entries > 10 in ifile2.txt)
```

Kindly note: The average should be taken over the selected values only i.e. those are > 10 only e.g.

```
(30+40+29+31+550/5) in ifile1.txt
```

I asked a similar question here [Difference between two files after average using shell script or awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540543/difference-between-two-files-after-average-using-shell-script-or-awk) and tried like this, but getting error.

```
awk '($0>10) && !/9000|9999/{a[ARGIND]+=$0;b[ARGIND]++}END{print a[1]/b[1]-a[2]/b[2]}' file1 file2
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @anubhava .. It is -97.33. A.M.D has tried it. But still not solved. The average should be taken over considered values only i.e. those are > 10 only. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this awk:

```
awk '$1>10 && $1 !~ /^(9000|9999)$/{a[ARGIND]+=$1; b[ARGIND]++}
       END{printf "%.2f\n", a[1]/b[1]-a[2]/b[2]}' ifile[12].txt
```

**Output:**

```
-97.33
```

Comment: May I ask you whether `ifile[12].txt` is same as `ifile1.txt ifile2.txt`? also `$1>10 && $1 !~ /^(9000|9999)$/` is same as `$1>10 && !/9000|9999/`? Thank you for solving my problem.

Comment: Yes `ifile[12].txt is same as ifile1.txt ifile2.txt` and `!/9000|9999/` may also match `90005` so you should use anchors as I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$1>10 && !/^9999$|^9000$/ {if(NR==FNR) {s1+=$1;n1++} else {s2+=$1;n2++}} END {print s1/n1 -  s2/n2}' file1 file2
```

For the first file (`NR==FNR`), for values greater than `10` and values not exactly equal to `9999 or 9000`, add the values to variable `s1`. Also increment the count variable `n1`. So `s1/n1` gives average for the first file. Similarly for the second file (`NR!=FNR`), update variables `s2` and `n2`. In the `END` block, print the difference of the averages.

Comment: There is still some problem. Because the average should be taken over considered values only i.e. those are > 10 only. Moreover may I ask you the difference between `!/9000|9999/` and `!/^9999$|^9000$/` ? Thank you so much for your answer.